# Диагональная линия в css. Как?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Как сделать "**декоративную**" (диагональную) линию белого цвета шириной `1px` для блока.
 При изменении размера блока, линия должна оставаться по диагонали (**являлась адаптивной**)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью js можно, например, сделать так:

```js
var a = $('.wrapper').height(); //получаем высоту прямоугольника
var b = $('.wrapper').width(); // ...и его ширину

var d = Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b); //высчитываем диагональ

var sin = a/d; //...синус угла между диагональню и стороной

var deg = Math.asin(sin) * (180/Math.PI); //...угол

 $('.inner').css({
    'width': d, //задаём длину диагонали
    'transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)' //...и угол наклона при первой загрузке страницы
  });

$(window).resize(function() { //меняем параметры при изменении размеров экрана

  b = $('.wrapper').width();

  d = Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b);

  sin = a/d;

  deg = Math.asin(sin) * (180/Math.PI);


  $('.inner').css({
    'width': d,
    'transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'
  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```css
.diagonal-line {
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 45%, #fff, transparent 54%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal-line">linear-gradient</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, надо только цвет линии поменять. Автор просил белый цвет

Comment: замечательно получилось

Answer (score 4):

Пример с svg:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  
  transition: all .2s;
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Диагональ */
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  right: 0;  
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%"><line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"/></svg>');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* Пример с изменением размеров блока с диагональю */
.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520112341255-f0659ca8db5f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=46514ba8b182c06c1d4c732ad829bc6b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">  
</div>
  
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520100021416-5e0301d08ac3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=54c4a341abe652d9f674834b3dd75597&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">  
</div>
```

Comment: диагональ не видно

Answer (score 2):

С помощью **JS** и **Linear-gradient**

```js
function myDeg() {
  h = $("div").height();
  w = $("div").outerWidth();
  deg = Math.atan(h / w);
  $("div").css("background", "linear-gradient(" + deg + "rad, mediumorchid calc(50% - 1px), white 50%,  mediumorchid calc(50% + 1px), mediumorchid 100% )");
}

myDeg();
$(window).resize(function() {
  myDeg();
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: mediumorchid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, но как вариант:

- задать блоку `position: relative`,
- разместить внутри него блок с `position: absolute`,
- задать ему `border-bottom: 1px solid #someColor`
- и применить `transform: rotate(someAngle)`.

Вроде бы ничего сложного.

Comment: только someAngle Вы как подбирать будете для адаптивного решения? он ведь в зависимости от размера блока каждый раз будет разный